# Telegram icon for font awesome not showing up

Tags: joomla, font-awesome

On my website built using Joomla 4, the following works fine (it displays the whatsapp icon):

```
<span class="fa fa-whatsapp">&nbsp;</span>
```

But this doesn't (trying to display the telegram icon):

```
<span class="fa fa-telegram">&nbsp;</span>
```

Although the same code for displaying telegram icon works on an older site built using Joomla 3.

I observed that, on old site, the following code is present in font-awesome.css and font-awesome.min.css. So I added the same code in the new site as well but it still doesn't work (just displays a box):

```
.fa-telegram:before {
    content: "\f2c6";
}
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Try asking on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: What version of Font Awesome are you using? Telegram was introduced in 4.7.